# Multi row Table Creation

Tags: tables

I am new in the world of Latex. I am trying to create a table as in the picture but I am not able to. Could someone please help me to create this table? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! For start search site for tables. more dozen similar tables are presented as answers here.

Comment: The search terms you may want to look for are `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`, see for example this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275480/36296